# Improving my R Code to calculate Z score of dataframe

Tags: r, loops, optimization

My quest is to generate an R code for calculation of Z-scores then outputting it to file. While the scripts works, I have some questions about some lines that are confusing to me.
Input.txt:

```
GeneID  GeneID-2    GeneName    TSS-ID  Locus-ID    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5
ID1 X1  Zranb2  TSS1    Loc1    22.49161667 14.7231 19.62885833 26.16171667 39.3109
ID2 X2  Lphn2   TSS2    Loc2    6.439735    5.920786667 8.883331667 7.696353333 10.46969333
ID3 X3  Rpf1    TSS3    Loc3    30.67975    20.93751667 27.30251667 31.55653333 58.57418333
ID4 X4  Ctbs    TSS4    Loc4    1.916071667 1.943611667 2.696701667 3.130295    2.74012
ID5 X5  Spata1  TSS5    Loc5    0.715265667 0.3318745   0.4183155   0.961065833 1.10731
ID6 X6  Sap30bp TSS6    Loc6    21.65946667 23.84386667 28.39683333 25.32866667 26.96016667
ID7 X7  Recql5  TSS7    Loc7    7.541321667 4.674345    4.40599 3.24996 3.327395
ID8 X8  Itgb4   TSS8    Loc8    37.3442 51.58868333 51.58868333 44.84458333 42.44406667
```

I would like to generate Z-score for data columns starting at Sample 1 to end of columns.
Here is the R Code I wrote:

```
df <- read.table("Input.txt", row.names=1, header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="NA")
x<-df[,5:ncol(df)] #selects the columns after column 5, so just the data
p<-matrix(0, now(x), ncol(x)) #opens matrix. First issue: I used "0" as I saw other people on forums doing that, but i dont know its significance.It worked for me, so i kept it. Can anyone comment on this?
#Create a loop for row and columns
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
    p[i,j] <- (x[i,j]-rowMeans(x[i,]))/sd(x[i,])
}
}
```

The above scripts successfully generates the matrix. Is there a way to optimize it or is this a reasonable approach? It is a bit slow with my huge datasets, but it gets the work done.

When outputting the file, I am getting my headers shifted. My goal is to output the first column of df as rownames, then each sample name as header. To that end, I used:

```
rownames(p) <-rownames(df)
colnames(p) <- colnames(df[,5:ncol(df)])
write.table(p, file = "Zscore.txt", append = FALSE, quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

Output file looks like:

```
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 
ID1 -0.212153637    -1.048074183    -0.520196808    0.182762424 1.597662204
ID2 -0.780453984    -1.061276795    0.541869723 -0.100449696    1.400310753
ID3 -0.216506298    -0.890314297    -0.450087937    -0.1558648  1.712773332
ID4 -1.064932662    -1.013415279    0.395343854 1.206440228 0.476563859
ID5 0.02537058  -1.119050742    -0.861024653    0.759083238 1.195621576
ID6 -1.35974252 -0.52968526 1.200411349 0.03452872  0.654487711
```

The header is shifted to the left. Also, If I want to include all the first 5 columns of the df in my output file, how can this be done?

Lastly, can you please advise between the difference of Zscore method calculation I have above and the scale function discussed in other questions?

Comment: Many things in R are vectorized, including basic things like substraction and division.

Comment: So? How does that relate? Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: i missed that. now i did. thanks @akrun

Comment: Should the green check mark spared only for the best solution- Please advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `rowSds` from `matrixStats` and do the computation in one step.

```
library(matrixStats)
dfN <- df[6:ncol(df)]
(dfN-rowMeans(dfN))/(rowSds(as.matrix(dfN)))[row(dfN)]
#      Sample1     Sample2    Sample3     Sample4    Sample5
#1 -0.21215364 -1.04807418 -0.5201968  0.18276242  1.5976622
#2 -0.78045398 -1.06127680  0.5418697 -0.10044970  1.4003108
#3 -0.21650630 -0.89031430 -0.4500879 -0.15586480  1.7127733
#4 -1.06493266 -1.01341528  0.3953439  1.20644023  0.4765639
#5  0.02537058 -1.11905074 -0.8610247  0.75908324  1.1956216
#6 -1.35974252 -0.52968526  1.2004113  0.03452872  0.6544877
#7  1.66627789  0.01983708 -0.1342732 -0.79815548 -0.7536863
#8 -1.34013679  0.98280311  0.9828031 -0.11700084 -0.5084686
```

---

Or a `base R` only method is

```
res <- t(scale(t(dfN)))
attributes(res)[3:4] <- NULL
```

Comment: That works! But when I output Zmatrix=(dfN-rowMeans(dfN))/(rowSds(as.matrix(dfN)))[row(dfN)]    i still get the headers shifted to the left. Also, how can I still add the remaining columns from the initial df. Note that the 6 should be a 5 in your code to match the data above.

Comment: @BioProgram It may be because one of the columns in your data is `row.names`, which I used as the first column.  You can just `cbind` i.e. `cbind(df[1:5], res)` where `res <- (dfN-rowMeans(dfN))..`

Comment: Great to learn about cbind. yet when i use it , I am still missing the very first column.

Comment: @BioProgram Then, you may not have that column in the initial dataset.  Instead it would `row.names` .  Therefore, `data.frame(rn= row.names(df), df[1:5], res)`

Comment: Yup, that perfectly works. Alternatively, I could remove row.names=1 from my initial line of df assignment and add 1 to dataframe limits.

Comment: can you elaborate on the attributes(res)[3:4] <- NULL ? what is this doing? I just saw this part of your answer.

Comment: @BioProgram  The `scale` function creates certain `attr` to the `matrix` output which may or may not be needed.  So, I just removed those attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100296/discussion-between-bioprogram-and-akrun).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you read you original data into a data frame called `df`, in tha base package, you can use apply function to get the result as follows:

```
resultMatrix <- apply(df[, 6:10], 1, function(x) (x - mean(x)) / sd(x))
```

To turn that into a data frame with the ID column bound from original, you can do as follows:

```
cbind(df$GeneID, data.frame(t(resultMatrix)))
```

Comment: While this works, the column name of df$GeneID is not automatically set. Further, can you please more the apply(df[, 6:10], 1, function(x) (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) ?I understood you are applying the function towards the end to the df columns, but what about the "1" before the function. What's that for?

Comment: You might want to look up the help page of the apply function in full details by doing "?apply" in r console. The 1 is saying 'row wise.' You can supply 2 for column wise. As for the first column name, you can change it using 'colnames()' or names(output)[1] <- 'someName'.